# Header files and multiple class usage (EDIT: forward declarations)

Tags: c++, file, class, header, include

I have a problem where I have several header files, and I need to include each of them in each other. Obviously, this cannot be done, because when I compile, the error "include nested too deeply" is thrown - as this essentially asks the compiler to enter an infinite include loop.

I could fix it using void pointers, but this seems like bad coding practice to me.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do, to aid understanding:

File-A:

```
#include "File-B"
#include "File-C"
class A
{
    public: B* p_B;
    public: C* p_C;
};
```

File-B:

```
#include "File-A"
#include "File-C"
class B
{
    public: A* p_A;
    public: C* p_C;
};
```

File-C:

```
#include "File-B"
class C
{
    public: B* p_B;
};
```

This just shows where each class declaration is needed. Surely there is a better solution to `void*`.

EDIT: I am already using include guards, this code is just to help you see what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using pointers or references to the other classes, and no code in the header file, you can use forward declarations:

```
class A; // Forward declaration

class C; // Forward declaration

class B
{
  public:
    A* p_A;
    C* p_C;
};
```

If code in the header file refers to any members of the other classes, you will have to include the entire definitions of the other classes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use **[include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)**:

```
#ifndef _FILE_A_H_
#define _FILE_A_H_

// Contents of FileA.h...

#endif
```

Possibly, also use **[forward declarations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)** to break cyclic dependencies between the definitions of your data structures.

In `FileA.h`:

```
class B; // No need to #include "FileB.h"

class A
{
public:
    B* pB;
};
```

In `FileB.h`:

```
class A; // No need to #include "FileA.h"

class B
{
public:
    A* pA;
};
```

Comment: It seems like the downvoter got upset at everybody who tried to answer this question...

Comment: Hi, forward declaration is what I am looking for, thanks I'll accept this answer in a second...

Comment: Good, although the struct declarations should probably be class declarations.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Isn't this answer sufficient? I thought you meant to accept it

Comment: @AndyProwl Yeah I thought I edited it to remove the stuff about include guards?

Comment: @EdwardBird: Does that prevent you from accepting it? It's not wrong information

Comment: @AndyProwl It's not wrong, it's just not relevant to the solution.

Comment: @EdwardBird: Well, after you edited your question mentioning that you do have include guards even though your code does not show it, maybe it is no more relevant. But having the information there won't make the answer unacceptable I think

Answer (score 1):

I would use include guards, which only include a certain file once.

```
#ifndef FILE_A
#define FILE_A
class A
{
    public: B* p_B;
    public: C* p_C;
};
#endif
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

It only includes the header file once per file.
You can also use #pragma_once, although it is not standard.

In the case that doesn't work, you can use a forward declaration.

```
class B;
class C;
class A
{
    public: B* p_B;
    public: C* p_C;
};
```

Comment: You've probably got it switched.  Use forward declarations first, then include the files.  The class definitions are required when access or referring to anything inside the other classes.

Answer (score 0):

This is why you have `#include <>` guards.

```
#ifndef _FILE_B
#define _FILE_B
#include "File-A"
#include "File-C"
class B
{
    public: A* p_A;
    public: C* p_C;
};
#endif
```

Comment: He doesn't want this question to be answered probably. He downvoted them all.

Comment: Well, it's his right to downvote us, I think we shouldn't do this just to take away his right to vote. On the other hand, I would be really curious to know his reasons.

Comment: @AndyProwl I see no reason to downvote. Not something you said was wrong, nor did I say something wrong. I have seen an uprise in such anonymous "mass" downvotes. I call them "Angry Downvoter".

Comment: It seems the AD decided to spare me for some reason. I can only imagine him to be the OP, also considering the consistent rep fluctuation. But this doesn't need to be the case, of course

Comment: AD doesn't seem to be the OP, the OP did not get a negative mark for DVing all of us. Since that's the case, the OP seems to be innocent @AndyProwl

Comment: You sure? I've seen the rep increasing by 1 after removing the downvote to my answer. But well, who cares.

Comment: @AndyProwl yeah I am sure. His last rep-change was on 20th Feb. :: _+5  18:42 upvote_ - 
_+5  18:40 upvote_ -  
_+5  18:38 upvote_ -
_-2  18:33 downvote_-  
_-2  18:31 downvote_

Comment: Ok, then it must be some other angry soul. Btw, my rep now decreased by 2 and I haven't been notified of any downvote, so the system may just be losing notifications.

Comment: @AndyProwl a glitch on StackOverflow perhaps?